# StringBuilder - StreamWriter doesn't write + symbol to csv

Tags: c#, csv, character-encoding, stringbuilder, streamwriter

I have a simple case which stuns me since I can't pin what I am doing wrong ...
I have tried a `StringBuilder` and `StreamWriter` but get the same results.

I want to add a `+` symbol in front of a string, I am iterating doing this. I can clearly see the `+` being added while debugging, in all occasions I tried, yet when I open the csv the leading `+` symbol is nowhere to be seen.

These are my attempts:

```
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(pathToCsv))
{
   // iterating and doing stuff ...

   value = string.Format(@"+32" + value);
   // value = "+32" + value;
   // value = @"+32" + value;

   writer.WriteLine(value); // I can always see here the +32 being written to the string
   writer.Flush();
}

StringBuilder sbOutput = new StringBuilder();

// same attempts as the code above
value = string.Format(@"+32" + value);
sbOutput.AppendLine(value);

// after iterating
File.WriteAllText(path, sbOutput.ToString()); // here as well I can clearly see the +32 being written and present in the sbOutput variable
```

What am I missing here?

Thank you for any feedback!

Comment: why are you calling `string.Format` instead of just `value = "+32" + value;`?

Comment: What are you using to view the CSV - have you tried notepad or VSCode?

Comment: I copy/pasted your code and it ran just fine, producing the expected results (I checked by opening the file in notepad). There must be something else going on that you haven't shared. Please post sample code that reproduces the behavior, and/or let us know how you're reading the file.

Comment: @RufusL, ... oh my, I it good in other editors! I was using Microsoft Excel ...
Thank you so much! You can post as answer if you want, I would accept it with pleasure! For the record I used string.Format out of desperation :)